Horror with a girl getting tricked into thinking her parents are dead
The scene is about a girl coming home and finding a note by her parents saying they are on holiday, or away somewhere. The note said they took a specific flight. Then the girl turns on the tv and then there is a newscast about that specific plane, that it has crashed or exploded or something. And then she gets upset. I’m not sure if she realizes it’s a trick or not. 
I was thinking Beetlejuice or something, but I can’t find anything online. 
It was in color, maybe ‘90 of early ‘00, but it’s a vague memory.

What did she do as a result of this? From what you've said, there must have been some development letting you know that she was tricked. What was it?

You're probably thinking of a scene from The Craft (1996), near the end when the rest of the coven attacked Sarah.








A newcomer to a Catholic prep high school falls in with a trio of outcast teenage girls who practice witchcraft and they all soon conjure up various spells and curses against those who even slightly anger them. 

